# Определить часовой пояс по адресу на Python

Tags: python

у меня есть список словарей с адресами, к примеру:

```
list = [{'адрес': 'г Омск'}, {'адрес': 'г Екатеринбург, ул Чапаева, д 14 к 6, кв 141'}
```

Хочу получить такой список со словарями:

```
list = [{'адрес': 'г Омск', 'часовой пояс': '+6'}, {'адрес': 'г Екатеринбург, ул Чапаева, д 14 
к 6, кв 141', 'часовой пояс': '+5'}
```

Подскажите, как сделать.

Comment: Я бы попробовал искать по городу, пример для поиска в гугле `python get timezone from city name`, пример найденного: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505501/get-timezone-from-city-in-python-django

Comment: @gil9red Да, там интересный код, хотя и под старые версии библиотек. Правда, для Омска какая-то странная зона, не ровное число часов выдаётся: `<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Omsk' LMT+4:54:00 STD>`

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, впервые вижу такой часовой пояс :)